# What is cause of dyld error in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

A simple swift app I built is returning two dyld errors in the debugger pain in Xcode 8.3.2. The apps worked on my iPhone (7 running iOS 10.3.2) and iPad (4 running iOS 10.3.1) for a few weeks but then would crash immediately on launch without even loading the first page. I updated my provisioning profile (which had expired) and attempted to reload the app on my iPhone and iPad. Both devices show just white screens when connected to my Mac and attempting to launch the app in Xcode. Any idea what might be causing this error? [dyld error screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxN26.png)

[dyld error screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdA5v.png)

Comment: I remember it has something to do with compiling, something wrong in your target or frameworks, I'm not quite sure

Comment: try `clean` your project then `build`

Comment: Thank you, the clean command fixed the problem!

Comment: Please either delete the question or answer it - otherwise, it clutters up the Q & A intention of the site. You may always answer your own question. Glad you fixed things!

Answer (score 0):

Using the product->clean in Xcode fixed the problem, thank you rudydydy.

This appears to have been a compiler induced error.